# [[Soundlib3]] Sound Library and delphi - How do add reverb (signal processing in soundlib3)

Tags: delphi, audio, signal-processing

How do I use Soundlib3 in Delphi to apply reverberation to the sound output ?

Comment: You'd better off focus on the specific problem you are about to solve, since library recommendations are off-topic here at SO as well as speculations about making of FruityLoops.

Comment: Well.. I am an advanced programmer (know all the basics and standards of a programming language) So my problems are very custom, 3rd party-specific and non-universal. Sorry for the audience.. but this site is in use to me for no longer if I cannot solve problems like this.

Comment: Reverb is very trivial, you know.

Comment: Yes. And it deserves down votes.It is enough for me to know if this particular library is capable of adding reverb to output.. I have no idea how to approach as I don't see any information regarding the reverb and delphi.

Comment: Then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34670788/edit) your question to state your **specific** inquiry clearly.

Comment: Yes, removed my vote. However, I doubt you'll get an answer.

Comment: I might, but probably in a long time. And I might not like it.

Comment: Soundlib3 hasn't been updated for eight years.  If you're writing something new, it really doesn't make sense to build it on top of a dead, unsupported library.  If you're trying to write something like FL you really should be thinking about something like ASIO/VST : http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphiasiovst/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot; SoundLib3 currently does not support reverberation or echo.  A cursory read of [the documentation](http://www.crossfire-designs.de/download//sourcecode/sl3doc/soundlib.xml#tsc_setenvironmenttype) reveals :

```
procedure setEnvironmentType(entype : longword);
```

> This function is currently NOT supported. It will set the type of environment. According to this, reflections, echoes and hall effects can be calculated.

See also

```
procedure setEnvironmentSize(size : tSVector);
```

> This function is currently NOT supported. It will set the size of the environment. All values are in metres. According to this, reflections, echoes and hall effects can be calculated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying and answering the question. Just one question though. What means that "the function is currently NOT supported". It means it is deprecated (cannot be guaranteed for proper use), obsolete - outdated buggy or slow in some manner ?

Comment: @Malina If I had to guess, it's probably a placeholder for something they intended to implement but never got around to.  SoundLib3 never got past beta, but you'd have to check the source code if you wanted a definite answer.